# Настроить api сервер laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

Пишу небольшой проект, и возникли проблемы при деплое проекта на сервер. Все запросы к **Laravel** идут через `public/index.php`, что не очень удобно. Рядом с ним лежит фронт на **Vue 3**. Запросы отправляются через `axios`. Все вроде бы хорошо, но вот незадача. **Laravel** требует от меня `csrf-токен`, который я не знаю где получить, из-за этого постоянно ловлю `401`. Приходится искать костыли и сначала авторизовываться в самом Laravel. Только после этого все запросы проходят нормально.
Пробовал копаться в `.htaccess`, но все безуспешно.

[image: Структура сервера]

В папке `backend` лежит сам проект на **Laravel**. Рядом лежит фронт на **Vue**.

Все запросы идут так: `www.домен.ru/baclend/public/index.php/` (путь к контроллеру)
После этого получаю ответ `401`.
В дополнении к **Laravel** идет `laravel/passport` для авторизации. Токены от него валидные.

Может кто знает как обойти это чудо?

Comment: так может надо прочитать книгу по ларевелу, прежде чем какие-то лютые костыли с ручным прописыванием `/backend/public/index.php/путь к контроллеру` городить?

Comment: чо касается csrf то можете пробросить его в meta индекса или отключить при желании

Answer (score 0):

В Laravel авторизуете пользователя (обычными методами, с использованием роутов без всяких index.php), получаете токен. Храните этот токен в storage своего фронта. При ответе сервера что токен устарел отправляете пользователя на авторизацию.